# Ruby Time and range inclusive/exclusive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time, activesupport

Right now I have a helper method that looks at a relative time range to determine what meal you are currently in.

```
def calculate_meal(time)

# Evening snack from midnight to 2:00am
# Morning Snack from 2:00:01am to 6:00am
# Breakfast 6:00:01am to 11:00 am
# Lunch 11:00:01am to 4:00pm
# Dinner  4:00:01 pm to 10:00pm
# Evening Snack 10:00:01pm to midnight
millisecond = 1
second = 1000
minute = 60*second
hour = 60*minute

if time.is_a? Hash

  time_hour     = time[:hour]
  time_minutes  = time[:minute]
  #time_sec      = time.sec
  #time_millisec = time.strftime("%L").to_i
  total_time = ((time_hour*60+time_minutes)*60)*second

elsif [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone,Time].include? time.class

  time_hour     = time.hour
  time_minutes  = time.min
  time_sec      = time.sec
  time_millisec = time.strftime("%L").to_i
  total_time = ((time_hour*60+time_minutes)*60+time_sec)*second+time_millisec

end

puts total_time
case total_time
when 0..(hour*2)
  return :evening_snack
when ((hour*2+millisecond)..(6*hour))
  return :morning_snack
when ((6*hour+millisecond)..(11*hour))
  return :breakfast
when ((11*hour+millisecond)..(16*hour))
  return :lunch
when ((16*hour+millisecond)..(22*hour))
  return :dinner
when ((22*hour+millisecond)..(24*hour))
  return :evening_snack
end
end
```

I am currently breaking up the range into milliseconds but is there a better way to use inclusive/exclusive ranges that deal with time in Ruby so that all times and cases are covered , instead of having holes like it currently does now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `...` to exclude the end point but include the start point. So something along the lines of:

```
def calculate_interval(point)
  case point
  when 0...10
    "first"
  when 10...20
    "second"
  else
    "third"
  end
end

calculate_interval(0)  # => "first"
calculate_interval(5)  # => "first"
calculate_interval(10) # => "second"
calculate_interval(20) # => "third"
```

In your particular case, you should be able to do the following:

```
case total_time
when 0...(hour*2)
  return :evening_snack
when ((hour*2)...(6*hour))
  return :morning_snack
when ((6*hour)...(11*hour))
  return :breakfast
when ((11*hour)...(16*hour))
  return :lunch
when ((16*hour)...(22*hour))
  return :dinner
when ((22*hour)..(24*hour)) # inclusive range depending on how you want to handle midnight
  return :evening_snack
end
end
```

Simply replacing `..` with `...` should do what you want.

As an aside, if you have access to `ActiveSupport::Time`, you should have access to the [`seconds_since_midnight`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-seconds_since_midnight) instance method which returns the seconds since midnight of a time object. That would simplify a lot of your initial computation.

For example,

```
Time.now.seconds_since_midnight # => 67595.181868
```

Comment: Its helpful how the seconds_since_midnight function takes into account the time zone offset of the time object.